# Change pull request that has a / on the name

Tags: github

I have a pull request with the following name `pr/amazing-pull-request`. I followed [this](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/changing-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request) tutorial but I'm only able to change the `amazing-pull-request` part of the name. It seems that GitHub doesn't allow me to change the full name.

Is there a way around to be able to change the full name?

Comment: Probably not. 'pr' is for 'pull request' and github uses that on the back end to distinguish PRs from normal branches.

Comment: Note that Pull Requests are specific to GitHub, and have very little to do with Git itself. (Bitbucket also has Pull Requests, but they're not the same as GitHub's. GitLab has "Merge Requests" instead of pull requests.) The actual name of a GitHub pull request is its internal ID number, which refers to an entry in a GitHub-side database that Git literally cannot see at all.